# Show Hidden Text Box when TWO radio boxes AND a button are clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, radio-button

Here is the HTML code of the two radio buttons and button

```
<body>


    <input data-image="small" type="radio" id="small" name="size" value="20" class="radios1"> 
    <label for="small"><span></span></label> 
    <div class="label">Small</div>    

    <input data-image="green" data-image1="small_green" type="radio" id="green" name="color" value="0" class="radios2" > 
    <label for="green"><span></span></label> 
    <div class="label">Green</div>    

    <button type="button" class="cart-btn" id="cartbutton" name="cart" value="5">Add To Cart!</button>

<div id="itemdv" style="display: none"> <input type="text" name="amount" class="item" value="8oz Green Tea"></div>

</body>
```

Here is the script I have so far. I got it to work with just the radio buttons but when I added the button script it stopped working.

```
<script>
const sizeSelector = 'input:radio[name=size]';
const colorSelector = 'input:radio[name=color]';
const cartSelector = 'button[name=cart]';

$(function () {
  
  // We can add the click event to all radio buttons by linking
  // their selectors with commans.
  $(`${sizeSelector}, ${colorSelector}, ${cartSelector}`).click(() => {    
    toggleWhenSmallAndGreenAndCartButton();
  });
  
});

const SMALL = 20;
const GREEN = 0;
const CARTBUTTON = 5;
function toggleWhenSmallAndGreenAndCartButton(){  
  let size = $(`${sizeSelector}:checked`).val();
  let color = $(`${colorSelector}:checked`).val();
  let cart = $(`${cartSelector}:checked`).val();
  $('#itemdv').toggle(size == SMALL && color == GREEN && cart == CARTBUTTON) && $('#itemdv2').toggle(size == SMALL && color == GREEN && cart == CARTBUTTON);
}


</script>
```

What I want to happen is for the textbox to show only when the id="small" radio AND the id="green" radio AND the id="cartbutton" are all clicked.

**Also, is there a way for the textbox to stay visible after all these conditions are met and not hide again if another selection is made?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a lot of code for a validity check

```js
const sizeSelector = 'input:radio[name=size]';
const colorSelector = 'input:radio[name=color]';
const cartSelector = 'button[name=cart]';

$(function() {

  $(`${cartSelector}`).click(() => {
    validityCheck();
  });

});

const SMALL = 20;
const GREEN = 0;
const CARTBUTTON = 5;

function validityCheck() {
  let $size = $(`${sizeSelector}`);
  let $color = $(`${colorSelector}`);
  
  let size_flag = $size.is(':checked');
  let color_flag = $color.is(':checked');

  $('#itemdv').toggle(size_flag && color_flag);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>


  <input data-image="small" type="radio" id="small" name="size" value="20" class="radios1">
  <label for="small"><span></span></label>
  <div class="label">Small</div>

  <input data-image="green" data-image1="small_green" type="radio" id="green" name="color" value="0" class="radios2">
  <label for="green"><span></span></label>
  <div class="label">Green</div>

  <button type="button" class="cart-btn" id="cartbutton" name="cart" value="5">Add To Cart!</button>

  <div id="itemdv" style="display: none"> <input type="text" name="amount" class="item" value="8oz Green Tea"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `disabled` attribute as follows

```js
document.getElementById("small").addEventListener("click", function(){ document.getElementById("green").removeAttribute("disabled");});

document.getElementById("green").addEventListener("click", function(){ document.getElementById("cartbutton").removeAttribute("disabled");});

document.getElementById("cartbutton").addEventListener("click", function(){ document.getElementById("itemdv").style.display = "block";});
```

```html
<body>


    <input data-image="small" type="radio" id="small" name="size" value="20" class="radios1"> 
    <label for="small"><span></span></label> 
    <div class="label">Small</div>    

    <input data-image="green" data-image1="small_green" type="radio" id="green" name="color" value="0" class="radios2" disabled="true" > 
    <label for="green"><span></span></label> 
    <div class="label">Green</div>    

    <button type="button" class="cart-btn" id="cartbutton" name="cart" value="5" disabled="true">Add To Cart!</button>

<div id="itemdv" style="display: none"> <input type="text" name="amount" class="item" value="8oz Green Tea" ></div>

</body>
```